# why overridden method calling from Subclass if i have done up-casting?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, upcasting

i have just started learning java::Inheritance and confused while mixing Up-Casting.

```
class Example{
     public void methodOne(){
        System.out.println("Example::Method_1");
     }

     public void methodTwo(){
        System.out.println("Example::Method_2");
     }
}

public class Test extends Example{

     public void methodTwo(){                  //Method overriding
        System.out.println("Test::Method_2");
     }

     public void methodThree(){
        System.out.println("Test::Method_3");
     }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Example exa = new Test();             // UpCasting

        exa.methodOne();                      // Printing Example::Method_1
        exa.methodTwo();                      // Printing Test::Method_2
        // exa.methodThree();                 // Error : can not find symbol
 }
}
```

may someone please explain, what happening here??

Comment: You may want to use the `@Override` annotation to mark that a method is overriding

Comment: i am beginner so sorry for any mistake, here i want to know why subclass method is calling if method is overridden ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using inheritance, the compile-time type of the reference to an object on which you call a method is only used to see (at compile time) if the method may be invoked.

But at the invocation time, it does not matter what that compile-time type is. What really matters in this case is the runtime type of the object. It is `Test`, so the method is searched on `Test` first.

For `methodOne()` it is a bit different: it is not overriden by `Test`, so the version from its superclass (`Example`) is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Class `Test` extends `Example` and overrides the implementation of the `methodTwo` while adding new method `methodThree`. Now in you main

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        Example exa = new Test();             // UpCasting

        exa.methodOne();                      // Printing Example::Method_1
        exa.methodTwo();                      // Printing Test::Method_2
        // exa.methodThree();                 // Error : can not find symbol
 }
```

Static type of the variable `exa` is `Example` hence API usage bounded by public methods defined in `Example` class therefore it's illegal to call `exa.methodThree()` (not defined it `Example`).

While for methods which are define at `Example` class there is a dynamic binding at runtime, which leads to concrete implementation based on the reference pointed by `exa` variable. Therefore `exa.methodTwo()` call leads to execution of overrided function, since dynamic type is `Test`. And since `Test` doesn't override `methodOne` calling `exa.methodOne()` will lead to the implementation defined by `Example`.

Answer (score 2):

if we create object of subclass and use reference of supper class then runtime time dynamic binding  happens means at runtime java decides that which thing should get called.
in your case :
1. `exa.methodOne();`  methodOne belongs to super class and its not being overridden in child class so  parent class method will be executed.
here if you create object like `Test test = new Test();` then also `test.methodOne()` will give you the same result.

2. `exa.methodTwo();`  here methodTwo is being overridden in child class so at run time  overridden method will get bonded and same will get executed.
3. in third case its giving error because you are using parent class reference  but methodThree() is not part of parent so compile error is being thrown.
   if wanna call third method then you can call like this :  `Test test = new Test();` `test.methodThree()`

FYI,

for safety we should always use @Override annotation in child call methods if we want to override any parent class method. it will help to avoid any method override glitches.